# Where do I get pymssql for a python script

Tags: python, macos

I am trying to run a python script using :-

python scriptname.py "someoptions"

When I do this it throws an error saying

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scriptname.py", line 7, in <module>
    import pymssql
ImportError: No module named pymssql
```

I am on a mac.Can someone tell me how can I get this package ? and where do i need to put it to?

This is the error that pip is showing :-

```
> Downloading pymssql-2.0.0b1-dev-20111019.tar.gz (5.0Mb): 5.0Mb
> downloaded  Running setup.py egg_info for package pymssql    Traceback
> (most recent call last):
>      File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
>      File "/private/tmp/my_new_env/build/pymssql/setup.py", line 41, in <module>
>        from Cython.Distutils import build_ext as _build_ext    ImportError: No module named Cython.Distutils    Complete output from
> command python setup.py egg_info:    Traceback (most recent call
> last):
> 
>  File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
> 
>  File "/private/tmp/my_new_env/build/pymssql/setup.py", line 41, in
> <module>
> 
>    from Cython.Distutils import build_ext as _build_ext
> 
> ImportError: No module named Cython.Distutils
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/pymssql/

The easiest way to install it is probably via [`pip`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) (or the older `easy_install`).

Comment: @Amber- I was using pip to install pymssql.I used the virtual env method but it is giving me this error (modified the OP).Do you have any idea how to correct this?